# Visual Composer loading slow (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, performance, plugins, tabs, load

I'm having a hard time with Visual Composer on Wordpress.  As you can see here - http://www.crlazio.info/wp/?page_id=22747 - the page is super slow to load. The reason might be that it loads the content of every single tab once the website is launched. Instead, I want it to load just the content of the tab of the current week, whereas the other tabs' content is loaded only once the user clicks on it. 
How can I fix it?

Comment: Where is this website hosted?

Comment: not really a way to answer this for you but look at this http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/bfUslW/http://www.crlazio.info/wp/?page_id=22747 i suspect you are using ajax to do a lot of work from outside urls to generate the page? ....can you not cache the page on the server for a start?

Comment: switch to Divi, visual composer is mega slow, always the same problem...